# ReportViewer 10 Error System.Drawing is not a trusted assembly

Tags: .net, vb.net, reportviewer

Getting an error when I am trying to run one of my reports on ReportViewer 10.

'An error occured during local report processing.  The report reference the code module 'System.Drawing', which is not a trusted assembly.

After some hunting on the internet, I added the lines :

```
Dim permissions As New PermissionSet(Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted)
Me.viewer.LocalReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(permissions)
```

but unfortunately I still get the error.  Is there something else I can do?

I'm using VB, .Net 4

Comment: The 'assembly' tag is for low level programming, not for .NET assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the settings in your app.config?

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
```

They must be disabled, this helped us eventually.

Best, Nikita